# Keep a base state in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having some troubles with states in React.
I don't find a way to keep a base-state (brings from parent's props) and a dynamic state (manages by the user). Let me explain:

I have two components: Parent & Child. Where:

Parent.js

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            children: []
        }
    }

    // Called some back-end service
    getData(){
        let arr = Array.from({...this.state.children});
        let service = new DataService();
        let data service.getAll();
        for(let i in data){
            // where data[i] = { boo: 'bye' }
            arr.push(<Child data={data[i].something} />);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            {this.state.children}
        )
    }        
}
```

And Child.js:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.state = props.data;
        this.baseState = {...props.data} // Cloned object 
    }

    handleChange(){
        // The point is change component's state but there is something weird
        this.setState({boo: 'hello'});

        console.log(this.state); // {boo: 'hello'}
        console.log(this.baseState); // {boo: 'hello'} --- why???
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={() => this.handleChange()}>I'm a child!</div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I change Child's state, the baseState changes too! I cloned the object to avoid this behavior but I don't know what is happening.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is props.data a nested object?

Comment: That's right! @BrianLe

Comment: Spread operator only makes a shallow copy so that’s probably the  problem in your case

Comment: I used Object.assign({}) and I had the same issue. What could I do? @BrianLe

Comment: Object.assign({}) is spread operator when transpiled. Why do you need to keep a base state?

Comment: @BrianLe I needed to know if something has change to enable a update-data-button. A previous filled form, for example. If the user changes some value over the previous data, enable the button to send data to back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

My problem was to make a shallow copy from parent's props. I use **lodash** library to clone the object and keep the same properties:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';    

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.state = props.data;
        this.baseState = _.cloneDeep(props.data); // Cloned object
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to copy a state passed (and updated) by props in a local scope variable ? I warn you, that's an anti-pattern and should be avoided. Try to use directly the props in render or lift the child state to the parent level.
Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: So you found it, congrats. However deep cloning is not a good way of doing that, it’s an anti pattern and will cause performance issues

Comment: @BrianLe what would you recommend?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I'm gonna try to set my state from props outside constructor!

Comment: @Gutty, user directly this.props.data.myProperty inside render, if you need to manipulate the prop do it in the parent state and you'll get it for free in your child component. If your child components need to change the state derived from props maybe you are fallen in an antipattern and you need to lift your state up